# dynamically create and deploy nodejs app from octopusdeploy to Azure Web app with correct node and npm version

Tags: node.js, powershell, azure, automation, octopus-deploy

The goal is to be able to create feature branch deployments on the fly.  Our setup:

- GITHUB
- Teamcity
- Octopus Deploy
- Azure Web Apps

A developer would commit / push code to Github on a new feature branch.  Teamcity would build all feature branches as they are created or updated.  Assuming a successful build it would create an artifact of the required files and push it to Octopus deploy.  This would then determine the Azure Web app name, create it and push the files to it.

[image]

Above is the Teamcity build steps (currently very basic just trying to get first principles).

The push package to octopus has creates the following artifact

```
**\* => %vcsroot.branch%-Recolight.web.%RecolightWebBuildVersionNumber%%build.number%.zip
```

This creates the package in Octopus:

[image]

Octopus deploy has 3 main steps:

- Determine App instance name
- Ensure web app
- Deploy web app

step 1:

```bsh
$version = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Release.Number"]
$environment = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Environment.Name"]
$subscriptionId = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Action.Azure.SubscriptionId"]
$uniquifier = $subscriptionId.Split("-")[0]

Write-Host "Package Version: $version"

$name = "### UNKNOWN ###"
$isPreRelease = $version -match "-(?<name>\p{L}*)"
if ($isPreRelease) {
    $name = $matches['name']
} else {
    $name = $environment
}

$appInstanceName = "$name-$uniquifier"
$webAppName = "$projectName-$appInstanceName"

Set-OctopusVariable -name "AppInstanceName" -value $appInstanceName
Write-Output "AppInstanceName: $appInstanceName"
```

step 2)

```bsh
$projectName = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Project.Name"].Replace(".", "-")
$appInstanceName = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Action[Determine App Instance Name].Output.AppInstanceName"]
$azureLocation = $OctopusParameters["AzureLocation"]

$webAppName = "$projectName-$appInstanceName"
Write-Output "WebAppName: $webAppName"

$existingWebApp = Get-AzureWebSite -Name $webAppName
if ($existingWebApp) {
    Write-Host "Web App named $webAppName already exists, no need to provision it."
} else {
    Write-Host "Creating new Web App named $webAppName in $azureLocation..."
    New-AzureWebSite -Name $webAppName -Location $azureLocation
}

Set-OctopusVariable -name "WebAppName" -value $webAppName
Set-OctopusVariable -Name "WebAppUrl" -Value ("https://{0}.azurewebsites.net" -f $webAppName.ToLowerInvariant())
```

step 3)

this is a built in Octopus deploy feature:

```
Deploy an Azure Web App master-Recolight.web from Octopus Server (built-in)
```

The zip file that is deployed contains:

[image]

the package json file is:

```
{
  "name": "recolightweb",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "compile": "gulp compile",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "start": "concurrent --kill-others \"gulp watch\" \"node ./bin/www\"",
    "postinstall": "typings install && gulp build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-fontawesome": "^0.5.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "angular2-modal": "^2.0.0-beta.13",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.6.4",
    "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",    
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "js-yaml": "^3.4.3",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "ng2-completer": "^0.1.10",
    "ng2-dnd": "2.0.1",
    "ng2-tooltip": "0.0.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^4.3.3",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.12.0",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "jadeify": "^4.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.17",
    "systemjs-plugin-text": "0.0.9",
    "tslint": "^3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "yargs": "^4.7.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.5.0",
    "npm": ">=3.10.6"
  }
}
```

All the files from the zip are extracted during the deploy process and end up under the wwwroot folder (I can see the when using powershell with Kudu).

My understanding is that the engines section should ensure that the Azure web app will be setup for node and npm correctly.  when I check the versions via powershell in Kudu they are not up to that version.

Is there a way to be able to automatically provision an azure web app and ensure its node and npm versions are up to date?

**UDPATE**

As per Gary's suggestion I have added the .deployment and deploy.cmd created via the azure-cli into SC. I can confirm that it was deployed to d:\home\site\wwwroot but it didn't seem to do anything else.  node and npm are still the same version, and node_modules was not created.  Not sure if msdeploy doesn't cause this to run be run.  I tried doing it on the existing web app, and deleting it and creating a whole new one.

Comment: It seems that the deployment task hasn't detected that was a node.js project, and still treated as a .net project. Could you please try to add 2 deployment scripts `.deployment` and `deploy.cmd` in your root directory of the package, via executing Azure-Cli command `azure site deploymentscript --node`. Refer https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script for details.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT I gave it a go, but nothing happened.  I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: one thing I noticed whilst messing with the deploy.cmd is it has its path reference to d:\home.  where as all my code is installed at d:\home\site\wwwroot.  not sure if the script should be at the "home" folder  or "wwwroot" for it to be actioned

Comment: To check the Node,js runtime version, could you please try to use `process.version` in node.js scripts. And the node.js version in KUDU env, is controlled by `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` of **App Settings**.

Comment: I was not able to get msdeploy to use the KUDU process, seems to be purely linked to GIT.  I did how ever manage to get it to work: create a triggered webjob that calls a deploy.cmd that will do the npm install.  The webjob can be triggered from a URL.  So when the files are deployed trigger the webjob and your site should be up